# Geolocation: How to figure out of the user is on site or off site

Tags: javascript, geolocation

How to accurately identify whether a user is on site or off site?

The client in Hong Kong wishes to track on site booking for a bar on the top floor of this building. However, a user may book the venue while dining in the restaurant on the ground floor.

Is there a way to do this better?

## Edit: I have tried the following:

- Geolocation - when they are in the same building, the location is the same
- 4G IP address - looks like the IP address remains the same unless the user reboots
- Time - tried using a hard number like 10 min, but this is kinda like a kludge

Comment: Is WiFi available?  If so, you may be able to use the remote IP address

Comment: Better than what? You haven't posted what you've tried, or what you want an answer to be better than.

Comment: @user2182349 Right, if we try to see if the user uses the restaurant's IP. However, this won't capture all users. Many of them may also be using their own 4G.

Comment: @RobG thanks for the suggestion, updated updated what I have tried. None is fail-proof. Any suggestions?

Comment: HTML5 geolocation may allow you to access altitude and accuracy http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_geolocation.asp

Answer (score 0):

The geolocation API may be your solution.

```js
function getLocation() {
    if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          console.log("geolocation works"); 
          console.log(coords.latitude);
          console.log(coords.longitude);
          console.log(coords.altitude);
          console.log(coords.altitudeAccuracy);
       });
    } else {
      console.log("geolocation doesn't work"); 
    }
}
```

You will be doing something other than console logging obviously, but this may let you determine what floor someone is on if it's a large building.

Edit: to be clear, I know you mentioned you tried geolocation, but wanted to point out that altitude may be useful.